# How do I add action buttons to a FileChooserDialog?

Tags: rust, gtk-rs

When I try to show a file chooser dialog, it is missing the action buttons:

```
let dialog = FileChooserDialog::new(Some("Open File"), Some(&window), FileChooserAction::Open);
dialog.run();
```

[image: missing action buttons]

I found another way from another project:

```
let dialog = FileChooserDialog::new_with_buttons::<ApplicationWindow>(
    Some("Open File"),
    Some(&window),
    FileChooserAction::Open,
    &[
        ("_Cancel", ResponseType::Cancel),
        ("_Open", ResponseType::Accept),
    ],
);
```

The error message is:

```
no function or associated item named `new_with_buttons` found for type `gtk::FileChooserDialog` in the current scope
```

Comment: Please format lines of code with a 4 space indent over triple backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to use `add_button` to add the buttons after creating the dialog and before showing it:

```
let dialog = FileChooserDialog::new(Some("Open File"), Some(&window), FileChooserAction::Open);
dialog.add_button("_Cancel", ResponseType::Cancel);
dialog.add_button("_Open", ResponseType::Accept);
dialog.run();
```